# WYSIWYG Froala Rails not show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, editor, wysiwyg, froala

I set wysiwyg Froala in my rails project, but always not show...
I create a simple project for test, but the problem still exists.
What step I probably miss?

env:Rails 5.1.5,ruby 2.4.1p111

```
    rails new froala
    rails g scaffold book title:string content:text
    rails db:migrate
```

I had add Gemfile

```
    gem 'font-awesome-rails'
    gem 'wysiwyg-rails'
```

run

```
    bundle install
```

add application.js in the following

```
//= require froala_editor.min.js

//= require plugins/align.min.js

//= require plugins/char_counter.min.js

//= require plugins/code_beautifier.min.js

//= require plugins/code_view.min.js

//= require plugins/colors.min.js

//= require plugins/emoticons.min.js

//= require plugins/entities.min.js

//= require plugins/file.min.js

//= require plugins/font_family.min.js

//= require plugins/font_size.min.js

//= require plugins/fullscreen.min.js

//= require plugins/image.min.js

//= require plugins/image_manager.min.js

//= require plugins/inline_style.min.js

//= require plugins/line_breaker.min.js

//= require plugins/link.min.js

//= require plugins/lists.min.js

//= require plugins/paragraph_format.min.js

//= require plugins/paragraph_style.min.js

//= require plugins/quick_insert.min.js

//= require plugins/quote.min.js

//= require plugins/save.min.js

//= require plugins/table.min.js

//= require plugins/url.min.js

//= require plugins/video.min.js

//= require languages/ja.js
```

add application.css in the following

```
*= require froala_editor.min.css

*= require froala_style.min.css

*= require font-awesome

*= require plugins/char_counter.min.css

*= require plugins/code_view.min.css

*= require plugins/colors.min.css

*= require plugins/emoticons.min.css

*= require plugins/file.min.css

*= require plugins/fullscreen.min.css

*= require plugins/image_manager.min.css

*= require plugins/image.min.css

*= require plugins/line_breaker.min.css

*= require plugins/quick_insert.min.css

*= require plugins/table.min.css

*= require plugins/video.min.css
```

add _form.html.erb in the following
[image]

Comment: Any errors in the browser's console? BTW, you're better off posting text rather than screenshots of text.

Comment: Could you make a screenshot of the developer tools? Are the any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem,it's rails version.
It's working in rails 5.0.1 now.